# Can't automatically deselect object when i press outside it

Tags: modeling

This might be a stupid question.

But you know how in Blender 2.8, unlike in Blender 2.79, we can automatically deselect object just by pressing outside it, for instance by pressing outside a cube or a camera?

For some weird reason i can't seem to do it anymore.
Now my Blender 2.8 selection tool work just like Blender 2.79, which sucks.
I tried to reinstall my Blender 2.8, but it doesn't seem to work.
(Maybe i just don't reinstall it properly, i don't know)

Can anyone help this noob to fix his simple problem?

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of user preferences, because I am still using 2.79, and clicking outside the object doesn't unselect anything.  However, you can unselect/select all objects by pressing "a" on the keyboard.  If you have objects selected that you don't want to be unselected, you simply hold down shift and click the object twice.  That should unselect it.  Hope that helps!

Comment: It works for me in 2.80. Maybe try a more recent build? Possibly try File/Defaults/Load Factory Settings in case you have changed a setting, as RBlong2us suggested. Personally I always use alt-a, but I'm old school ;)

Comment: I have no idea how to Load Factory Settings in 2.8 ....

Comment: In 2.80 factory settings is now `File->Defaults->Load Factory Settings`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Set a new selection]

Please, make sure you have selected *Set a new selection* icon.